# How do I post a comment instead of an answer?

Tags: discussion, comments

I'm trying to post a comment to an answer in the Forum, and I don't see a place to link on to do that.  I only see the interface for a full answer at the bottom of the page.  I need to post something in response to a comment that is commenting on an answer. What am I missing?  Here's the page:
[How to close watermarks window in QGIS Openlayers plugin?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24646/how-to-close-watermarks-in-openlayers-plugin/25695#25695)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the FAQ, you need 50 reputation to leave a comment https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

but "*You can always comment on your questions and answers, and any answers to questions you’ve asked, even with 1 rep."*

I guess it's a feature to avoid spam.

If you leave your comment as an answer, I can convert it for you.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.  I thought I wasn't supposed to leave a comment as an answer, because when a moderator converts it, I get a message to check the FAQs.  I did search through the FAQ for "comment" and didn't see that answer. Thanks for the link.